# Firebase Security Rules to verify Array key using push method

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Data:

```
post : {
    -K9u7JHeoMpjk_xZW0VK : {  }
}

Security Rules: post/{ postId }

-here postId = -K9u7JHeoMpjk_xZW0VK
```

So How do i verify postId is firebase dynamic key only, because i can set post/undefined or post/somevalueasstring.

Comment: It is not too difficult to check that a key is within the range of a push id, since it's just a string of 20 characters in a specific range. But this sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What specific (ab)use-case are you trying to prevent?

Comment: user able to set  post/undefined, i want to prevent them from doing so.Thanks for letting me about XY Problem.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. It's likely my lack of coffee. Can you add a snippet of code that demonstrates the exact write operation that you want to disallow?